# Query parquet files with apache drill is very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, apache, bigdata, apache-drill

I am using apache drill on a single node (I know that this is not the best case for drill). But I need to query a parquet file on local file system with 20 000 rows with the following statement:

SELECT * FROM parquetfile

This takes 6 seconds to deliver results. Why the hell is drill that slow? Any optimization tips? Thanks.
.

Comment: Show us the table schema.

Comment: What version of Drill do you use? Did you try to query this file with other tools? What is structure of the file? What is the size of the file? Did you check the log files? You can try CTAS also to create a new file and query it.

Comment: 80 % of the time is spent as "Wait time".
The file has 6 columns, every column is of type float.
The file is 110 MB large and has 15 000 000 rows.

Comment: Wait time is documented as "These fields represent the minimum, average, and maximum cumulative times spent by operators waiting for external resources." but parquet files are on same machine than drill service is running.

Comment: Do you want to output the whole content of a file (15 000 000 rows)? If so 6 sec can be normal case.
But in original question you have written the file involves 20 000 rows.